# Including a SUM in a multiple joined snowflake query

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am struggling to create a statement in a snowflake schema. I need to show a list of all products and associated tracks but also include a count of how many songwriters are attached to each track. 
My tables are:

```
Table: PRODUCT
-PRODUCT_ID
-ALBUM_ARTIST
-ALBUM_TITLE

Table: SONGWRITER
-SONGWRITER_ID
-FIRSTNAME
-LASTNAME

Table: SONG_SONGWRITER
-SONGWRITER_ID
-TRACK_ID
-OWNERSHIP_SHARE

Table: TRACK 
-TRACK_ID
-PRODUCT_ID
-TRACK_ARTIST
|TRACK_NAME
```

I tried the following, however, it errors due to the group by clause. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
SELECT prod.*, tra.TRACK_NAME,count(*) AS "Number of Songwriters"
FROM PRODUCT prod
INNER JOIN TRACK tra
ON tra.PRODUCT_ID=prod.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN SONG_SONGWRITER ssw
ON ssw.TRACK_ID = tra.TRACK_ID
GROUP BY prod.PRODUCT_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to do a sub-select to get this information.  Something more like this:

```
SELECT prod.*, tra.TRACK_NAME, ssw.songwriters_count as "Number of Songwriters"
FROM PRODUCT prod
INNER JOIN TRACK tra
   ON tra.PRODUCT_ID=prod.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT TRACK_ID, COUNT(*) as songwriters_count
     FROM SONG_SONGWRITER
     GROUP BY TRACK_ID
  ) ssw
  ON ssw.TRACK_ID = tra.TRACK_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was racking my brain over this for way to long!

Answer (score 0):

You should mention in the GROUP BY clause the columns you mentioned in the SELECT clause :

```
SELECT prod.*, tra.TRACK_NAME,count(*) AS "Number of Songwriters"
FROM PRODUCT prod
INNER JOIN TRACK tra
ON tra.PRODUCT_ID=prod.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN SONG_SONGWRITER ssw
ON ssw.TRACK_ID = tra.TRACK_ID
GROUP BY prod.PRODUCT_ID,prod.ALBUM_ARTIST,prod.ALBUM_TITLE
,tra.TRACK_NAME
```